# Прозрачный Label в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Нужно одно изображение (png формат с прозрачным фоном) наложить на другое. Делаю так, но прозрачный фон забивается стандартными серыми пикселями, а нужно чтобы они оставались прозрачными и из под них пробивался фон. Можно ли это как-то осуществить?

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

win = tkinter.Tk()

img_1 = Image.open('square.png')
img_photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_1)

img_2 = Image.open('circle.png')
img_photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_2)

square_label = tkinter.Label(win, image=img_photo1)
square_label.place(x=0, y=0)

sircle_label = tkinter.Label(win, image=img_photo2)
sircle_label.place(x=0, y=0)

win.mainloop()
```

[image: Получается так]

[image: А надо так]

Comment: [Labels don't support transparency.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31730201/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Label как и другие Tk widgets не поддерживает прозрачность. Поэтому, если разместить одну Label поверх другой, то верхняя будет загораживать нижнюю.

Чтобы наложить картинку с прозрачным фоном на другую картинку в Tkinter, можно [canvas](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm) использовать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=600, bg='white')
image_sky = tk.PhotoImage(file='sky.png')
image_sun = tk.PhotoImage(file='sun.png')
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=image_sky, anchor=tk.NW)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=image_sun, anchor=tk.NW)
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```