# Как картинку сделать прозрачной в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Доброе утро. У меня виджет Text и по верх его я хочу поставить картинку с прозрачностью, чтобы картинка выглядела как фон и притом виджет мог работать.
Может надо еще поработать с слоями если это возможно конечно. Подскажите как это риализовать

Comment: связанный вопрос [Прозрачный Label в tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/734266/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter стандартный модуль не поддерживает прозрачность на сколько я помню, нужно использовать PIL или ImagePhoto. Это все расширенные библиотеки Tk python. Слои вряд ли вам помогут.

- [Вопрос в этом духе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158552/how-to-use-an-image-for-the-background-in-tkinter)
- [На этом сайте основа работы с прозрачными    изображениями](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm)